# All values become the same when using stdClass() in a for loop

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have a function getComment below. Problem with this function is that

`$test->TestComments[$type]` will all contain the same values, namley the last comment made together with its username and timestamp.

```
public function getComment($test) {
    $Id = $test->Id;
    $localComment = new stdClass();
    $queryComment = $this->getResultCommentQuery($Id);
    $result = odbc_exec($this, $queryComment);
    $no_results = odbc_num_rows($result);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $no_results; $i++) {
        odbc_fetch_row($result, $i);
        $type = trim(odbc_result($result, "result"));
        $localComment->Comment = trim(odbc_result($result, "comment"));
        $localComment->Username = trim(odbc_result($result, "username"));
        $localComment->Timestamp = trim(odbc_result($result, "timestamp"));
        $test->TestComments[$type] = $localComment;//there are no unique
 //values here, every comment will have the same "timestamp", "comment", and "username", namley the last one.
echo($localComment->Comment);//If I do this I see that there are different values.
        }
        return $test; //But this will only contain a correct nr of array attributes with same content (last comment info), see bellow.
    }
```

For example what I get.

```
    TestComments":{"Pay":{"Comment":"Test","Username":"en","Timestamp":"2014-08-01 14:27:41.410"},
"Peak":{"Comment":"Test","Username":"en","Timestamp":"2014-08-01 14:27:41.410"}}
```

That is I get the same content twice instead of 2 rows with different values. Anyone see what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is odbc_result($result, "result") returns the same result(or no result) for all rows so $type is always the same. $test->TestComments[$type] gets overridden on each iteration and in the end you only have the last row. Can you var_dump($type) and see what value it gets on each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the use of

```
$test->TestComments[$type] = $localComment;
```

This is not doing what you think. It is actually copying a **reference** to the object to `$test->TestComments[$type]` and not the contents of the object itself.

So as you only have one actual `$localComment` object all of these references are pointing to that one object which will contain whatever was last placed into the object.

What you actually want to do is CLONE the object, which creates a copy of the object and not just assigns a reference to the original object.

So change this line

```
$test->TestComments[$type] = $localComment;
```

To

```
$test->TestComments[$type] = clone $localComment;
```

and your existing code should work as you expect.

Comment: Finally the penny dropped and I worked out what was actually wrong. I changed the answer to reflect the actual error and the correct fix. I hope you dont mind and if it is wrong I am sure you can remove the correct answer credits.